# What is the best way to get data from other subdomain with different database?

Tags: php, database, get

I have a mainwebsite and a subdomain. They both have different databases, config files, ... The file getinfo.php in my subdomain gets the numbers of active topics. What is the best way to display this on my homepage? How can I execute the getinfo.php, get that data and display it on my homepage? Or is there another possibility to do that?

I think it is not a good idea to connect to a second database.

Comment: If both sites are on the same server, why can't you just read the other database directly? It's supported in SQL: `select tablename.fieldname FROM databasename.tablename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're opposed to connecting to multiple databases simultaneously. But, if you're so flatly against it then I'm sure you have a good reason to be. A hacky solution would be to write a page on the subdomain to provide the data from the database you don't want to connect to via some easily-parsable method, like `serialize`d string, JSON, or XML. Then, use cURL on your other page to fetch this data. There are obvious security concerns that you'll have to account for, such as how you'll ensure the other page isn't accessed by anything but your script.

Comment: Ok, but connecting to a second database to display only one thing on my full website isn't a good idea I think, or am I wrong?

Comment: If they're on the same server, the overhead is probably negligible. Think of what you'll be doing in the future, though. There's only one query now, but could there be more later? If there will be more, would you rather a hacky approach or true support for multiple database connections?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 databases you can't do other than connect to the 2 databases. And if they are on the same server you won't get that much overhead

Comment: Is it not possible to read a file in my subdomain that send a query to the database and displays the number of active topics?

Answer (score 0):

Send a cURL request from your homepage to a PHP file on your subdomain that takes that cURL request and outputs the HTML for your top posts. Then just echo the $output of the cURL.